# Splitting a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

Let's say I have this string:

```
"param1,r:1234,p:myparameters=1,2,3"
```

...and I would like to split it into:

```
param1
r:1234
p:myparameters=1,2,3
```

I've used the split function and of course it splits it at every comma. Is there a way to do this using regex or will I have to write my own split function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would try something like this:

```
,(?=[^,]+:.*?)
```

Basically, use a positive look-ahead to find a comma, followed by a "key-value" pair (this defined by a key, a colon, and more information [data] (including other commas). This should disqualify the commas between the numbers, too.

Comment: Demo found here: http://www.ideone.com/Xa7YR -- Although, this also requires that the information be better formatted. Either way I think this isn't going to be more successful than a human parsing it (but maybe at least get you thinking).

Comment: Brad, This is what I'm looking for and if not pretty darn close but I think this will do. Thank very much for your help!!!

Comment: @DavidSunderland: no problem, hope it at least gets you a good part of the way there. But without some form of patter it's hard to tell what's a "data" comma and what's a delimiting one.

Comment: FYI, that `.*?` at the end is completely useless; it will always match zero characters.  The solution works anyway because you don't *need* to match anything after the colon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `;` for separating values which makes easy to work with it.

Since you have `,` for separation and also for values it is difficult to split it.

You have

```
string str = "param1,r:1234,p:myparameters=1,2,3"
```

**Recommended to use**

```
string str = "param1;r:1234;p:myparameters=1,2,3"
```

which can be splited as

```
var strArray = str.Split(';');

strArray[0];  // contains param1
strArray[1];  // r:1234
strArray[2];  // p:myparameters=1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you *would* write a split that knew which commas to split on there, honestly.

Unless it's a fixed number each time in which case, just use [the `String.Split` overload that takes an `int` specifying how many substrings to return at max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx)

If you're going to have comma-delimited data that's not always a fixed number of items **and** it could have literal commas in the data itself, they really should be quoted.  If you can control the input in any way, you should encourage that, and use [an actual CSV parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) instead of `String.Split`

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the response.  Yes this was a weird requirement requested from an end-user. Which is why I'm here. I didn't expect this person to enter in the multiple commas on p:myparameters=.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. You can't parse it with regex (or anything else) unless you can identify a consistent rule separating one group from another. Based on your sample, I can't clearly identify such a rule (though I have some guesses). How does the system know that `p:myparameters=1,2,3` is a single item? For example, if there were another item after it, what would be the difference between that and the `1,2,3`? Figure that out and you'll be pretty close to a solution.

If you're able to change the format of the input string, why not decide on a consistent delimiter between your groups? `;` would be a good choice. Use an input like `param1;r:1234;p:myparameters=1,2,3` and there will be no ambiguity where the groups are, plus you can just split on `;` and you won't need regex.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be changing your delimiter from "," to something like "|". Then you can split on "|" no problem. However if you can't change the delimiting character then maybe you could encode the sections in a fashion similar to CSV.

CSV files have the same issue... the standard there is to put double quotes "" around columns.

For example, your string would be "param1","r:1234","p:myparameters=1,2,3".

Then you could use the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser to split/parse. You can include this in c# even though its in the VisualBasic namespace.

[TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that:string[] str = System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex.Spilt("param1,r:1234,p:myparameters=1,2,3",@"\,");

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aaron but I don't want 1,2,3 to be split.